# How to show correct value using JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, parsing

I have `JSON` code which I want to parse but it is not parsing as I expected. I need to show only messages but it is showing me extra information like `Object`, `Array`. How to fix it?

```
var txt = "";
var json_string = JSON.stringify(data.json_data);
var json_object = JSON.parse(json_string, function(key, value){
    txt += value;
});
console.log(txt);
```

**Message in browser console:**

```
Enter the same password as above, for verification.  crud.js:45:25
Array [ <1 empty item> ]  crud.js:45:25 <-- DONT NEED TO SHOW
Email already exists.  crud.js:45:25
Array [ <1 empty item> ]  crud.js:45:25 <-- DONT NEED TO SHOW
Object {  } <-- DONT NEED TO SHOW
```

Comment: share your json_data

Comment: It will be hard cause JSON generated by Django/Python project. Question here is about JS code. When user enter invalid data to form I want to show error messages by AJAX.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got solution for you. Please check below code.

```
var data = {
    'json_data' : {
    'test1' : 'test1',
    'test2' : 'test2',
  }
}

var json_string = JSON.stringify(data.json_data);
console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(json_string));
var json_object = jQuery.parseJSON(json_string);
$.each(json_object,function(index, value) {
    console.log(index);
  console.log(value);
});
```

It will work.

Please check below link as well

https://jsfiddle.net/bnsk9pe7/

Comment: Thanks! I use `jQuery.parseJSON` instead of `JSON.parse`. Also use `$.each`. It works now! =)